# amqplib not connecting to localhost RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, node-amqplib

I went through several SO threads regarding this. Didn't work anything. But my case is different. In my case, nothing happens. Here is the code:

```js
import amqplib from 'amqplib'

const AMQP_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/'
const AMQP_QUEUE_NAME = 'email_queue'

function connectRabbitMQ() {
    console.log('Connecting to rabbit mq...')
    amqplib.connect(AMQP_URL, async (err: Error, connection: amqplib.Connection) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('This log doesn\'t print')
            throw err
        }
        console.log('This log doesn\'t print')
        
        // Listener
        const channel1 = await connection.createChannel()
        channel1.consume(AMQP_QUEUE_NAME, (msg) => {
            if (msg !== null) {
                console.log('Recieved:', msg.content.toString());
                channel1.ack(msg);
            } else {
                console.log('Consumer cancelled by server');
            }
        })

        // Sender
        const channel2 = await connection.createChannel()
        setInterval(() => {
            channel2.sendToQueue(AMQP_QUEUE_NAME, Buffer.from('something'))
        }, 1000)
    })
}

function launchServer() {
    console.log('Launching Server...')
    console.log('Connecting to MongoDB...')
    const MONGODB_URI = process.env.MONGODB_URI?.toString() || ''
    mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI, {}, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            return console.error('Error connecting to Mongo DB !')
        }
        console.log('CONNECTED TO MONGO DB')
        const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT?.toString() || '3000')
        app.listen(port)
        console.log('========= SERVER STARTED ========== PORT ' + port)
        connectRabbitMQ()
    })
}
launchServer()
```

Neither error nor success occur. The log doesn't get printed. Last log get printed is - `Connecting to rabbit mq...`

Comment: I am in the same position, the .connect does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

function `connectRabbitMQ` doesn't seems to be executed.
try appending this on last line of your code

```js
connectRabbitMQ();
```

Comment: Hi, I am aware of it and invoked the method. Added full code above. Please check.